# CreationalContext: should a custom Bean always call push() from its create() method?

Tags: java, cdi

The [CDI specification says, in part](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#creational_context):

> The implementation of `Contextual` [e.g. your custom `Bean`] is not required to call `push()`. However, for certain bean scopes, invocation of `push()` between instantiation and injection helps the container minimize the use of client proxy objects (which would otherwise be required to allow circular dependencies).

I have struggled with the real-world takeaway from this for a long time.

If I am writing a portable extension, and while doing so I am adding `Bean` instances to the container programmatically, does it do any *harm* to always call `creationalContext.push(this)` from within [my `Bean`'s `create(CreationalContext)` method](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/2.0/javax/enterprise/context/spi/Contextual.html#create-javax.enterprise.context.spi.CreationalContext-)?  Is there a real-world translation for what "certain bean scopes" means?

I'm looking for something like "if your `Bean` is going to be in `Frobnicator` scope, then don't bother to call `push()`, but if it's going to be in `Fizzbuzz` scope then you always want to do this".  Obviously I'd also like to understand the reasoning behind such advice.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a question worth asking on [CDI-dev mailing list](https://lists.jboss.org/mailman/listinfo/cdi-dev) for both, actual answer and a request for clarification in spec.

***As you yourself figured out, it is poorly documented so anything I will claim here I cannot support by quoting spec, so take it with a pinch of salt.***

From what I recall, this was used mainly for circular dependencies in injection. If you aren't doing that, then you are safe to ignore it. Furthermore, Weld solves classic circular injection for you, so this is only really relevant for `@Produces` and *maybe* also `@PostConstruct`.

The whole purpose of this is storing a "partially created" instance within a context in order to satisfy the resolution and proceed with creation of circularly dependent bean.